# I need to find the xpath for the following element as I am begineer in selenium?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
    input_id="client_user_name" 
    name="client_user_name" 
    type="text" 
    required="required" 
    placeholder="Username / Contact Number" 
    class="form-control input-sm ui-autocomplete-input" 
    value="" 
    autocomplete="off"
```

Comment: also i need to pass "saileshn" as parameter and select it from autosuggestion list

Answer (score 0):

Try to use that:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='client_user_name']")
```

or

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='client_user_name']")
```

or

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='form-control input-sm ui-autocomplete-input']")
```

and finally:

```
el.send_keys('saileshn')
```

but better read about xpath, it will help 100%